# excel vba autofilter

Tags: excel, vba

I have a database with titles that starts at row 2, being row 2 the titles and all other below the information. I have 11 columns on it.
The first row it will be a row to make a input search for the auto filter to work but i want only to do it for some of the columns.

i just want the auto-filter input to work on column E, F, H and I
All other's inputs should do nothing.

However when trying to set multiples criteria separately the auto-filter does not work, does not show nothing. It does only work when i write something on the E column if i start writing something on any other it shows nothing

Red background should be cells not editable
Green ones should be cells editable for search/filter

Button 1 is to add more able lines but for now i have not yet done that part, was trying to figured out the filter side firts

This is the code i have:

```
Option Explicit
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
ActiveSheet.Unprotect
Application.EnableEvents = False

Dim sht As Worksheet
Dim LastRow As Long
Dim DataRange As Range

Set sht = ActiveSheet
LastRow = sht.Cells(sht.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

Set DataRange = Range("A3:J" & LastRow)

If Target.Row = 1 Then
    If Target.Column > 1 Then
        If Target.Column = 5 Then
            Cells(Target.Row, 6).NumberFormat = "0"

            Cells(Target.Row, 9).NumberFormat = "General"
            Cells(Target.Row, 9).Value = "Figueira da Foz"
        End If
    End If
    DataRange.AutoFilter Field:=1, VisibleDropDown:=False
    DataRange.AutoFilter Field:=2, VisibleDropDown:=False
    DataRange.AutoFilter Field:=3, VisibleDropDown:=False
    DataRange.AutoFilter Field:=4, VisibleDropDown:=False
    DataRange.AutoFilter Field:=5, Criteria1:="*" & Cells(Target.Row, 5).Value & "*", VisibleDropDown:=False
    DataRange.AutoFilter Field:=6, VisibleDropDown:=False
    DataRange.AutoFilter Field:=7, Criteria1:="*" & Cells(Target.Row, 7).Value & "*", VisibleDropDown:=False
    DataRange.AutoFilter Field:=8, Criteria1:="*" & Cells(Target.Row, 8).Value & "*", VisibleDropDown:=False
    DataRange.AutoFilter Field:=9, VisibleDropDown:=False
    If Target.Column = 10 Then
        If Target.Value = vbNullString Then
            DataRange.AutoFilter Field:=10, VisibleDropDown:=False
        Else
            DataRange.AutoFilter Field:=10, Criteria1:=Cells(Target.Row, 10).Value, VisibleDropDown:=False
        End If
    End If
End If
If Target.Row = 2 Then
    Range("A" & Target.Row & ":J" & Target.Row).Locked = True
End If
If Target.Row > 2 Then
    If Target.Column = 5 Then
        Cells(Target.Row, 1).NumberFormat = "0"
        Cells(Target.Row, 1).Value = Target.Row - 2

        Cells(Target.Row, 2).NumberFormat = "yyyy-mm-dd"
        Cells(Target.Row, 2).Value = Now

        Cells(Target.Row, 3).NumberFormat = "hh:mm"
        Cells(Target.Row, 3).Value = Now

        Cells(Target.Row, 6).NumberFormat = "0"

        Cells(Target.Row, 9).NumberFormat = "General"
        Cells(Target.Row, 9).Value = "Figueira da Foz"

        Cells(Target.Row, 10).NumberFormat = "General"
        Cells(Target.Row, 10).Value = "Activa"

        Range("A" & Target.Row & ":J" & Target.Row).Interior.ColorIndex = 4
    End If
    If Target.Column = 10 Then
        If Target.Value = "Inactiva" Then
            Cells(Target.Row, 4).NumberFormat = "hh:mm"
            Cells(Target.Row, 4).Value = Now
            Range("A" & Target.Row & ":J" & Target.Row).Interior.ColorIndex = 3
        End If
        If Target.Value = "Activa" Then
            Cells(Target.Row, 4).Value = vbNullString
            Range("A" & Target.Row & ":J" & Target.Row).Interior.ColorIndex = 4
        End If
        If Target.Value = vbNullString Then
            Range("A" & Target.Row & ":J" & Target.Row).Interior.ColorIndex = 2
        End If
    End If
End If

Application.DisplayAlerts = False
ThisWorkbook.Save
Application.EnableEvents = True
ActiveSheet.Protect
End Sub
```

Comment: Your filtered range should include all the data, not just the header row.  Otherwise there is nothing to filter.

Comment: Not sure what you mean, cause if i place Range("A2:K20") instead Range("A2:K2") it will give the error "run time error 1004" not possible to execute autofilter of the range class

Comment: I did update the code with the one i have now and follow your advise... It's not giving any error and part of it it works with multiple criteria, however the column F (Target.Column 6) is not working cause it's a number (for some reason). The multiple criteria is working for E and H Column (both of them are text) but not for F (it's a number)

Comment: If column 6 is a number, then the code to filter it should be: DataRange.AutoFilter Field:=6, Criteria1:=Target.Value, VisibleDropDown:=False

Comment: Also, add this line at the beggining of the procedure: Application.EnableEvents = False and this one at the end: Application.EnableEvents = true

Comment: just updated the code with the one i have atm... The column F (target.column 6) when filled does not search correctly ... i did try to place target.value has you told but it cleans all the data, nothing is showed ...

Comment: ohh forgot to mentioned that column is a number... All the other's search inputs works but they are all text

Comment: to test i did try Criteria1:="*9*" OR Criteria1:="=*9*" but either ones of them works ...